# Check if at least one element is visible

Tags: jquery, html

I've a set of elements with the same class:

```
<div class="the_class"></div>
<div class="the_class"></div>
<div class="the_class"></div>
```

With jQuery, I want to check if at least one of these elements is shown. Something like:

```
if ($('.the_class').theFunction()) {
    ...
}
```

What can I use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) with [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to check if the element is visible. Use the class selector and if visible element count is *greater then zero* then it means atleast one element is visible.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kF2MR/)**

```
if($('.the_class:visible').length)
{

}
```